# How can round multiple inputs with the same id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.6

I did a script using **JQUERY 1.6** to round input, so when I type a long number my script will automatically round 2 decimals.

But is only working with the first input and is not working with other inputs with the same input ID

Here is the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/96428uk8/10/)

```
<script>
jQuery("#round_inputs").live("change", function(){
 input_values = parseFloat(jQuery("#round_inputs").val());
 if (isNaN(input_values)) input_values = "";
 jQuery("#round_inputs").val(input_values.toFixed(2));  
});  
</script>

<input id="round_inputs" size="20" style="text-align:right" type="text"/><br/>
<input id="round_inputs" size="20" style="text-align:right" type="text"/><br/>
<input id="round_inputs" size="20" style="text-align:right" type="text"/><br/>
```

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: You can't have duplicate IDs in the DOM.

Comment: You cannot do that. An id has to be unique in a document. There can only be one element with the same id. When you search for elements with some id you will always only get back _one_ element. It is impossible to return multiple elements with one id.

Comment: On a side note, `.live()` is deprecated and removed as of `1.8.3`. Use `.delegate()`, `.bind()` or `.on()` depending on your use case...

Comment: Use classes instead of ids. If you want multiple elements to behave the same way, you use classes. If you want only _one_ element to behave a certain way, you use ids.

Comment: Why negative points? I just was asking.

Comment: People downvote questions that are poorly asked or that show poor effort on the asker's part. You asked your question well, but I guess the error in the premise of your question made people think you should read tutorials before asking questions. I agree that SO isn't there to learn from scratch, but downvoting for that is a bit lame. Still, I recommend you read the [Web Dev Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, ID **must** be unique, so use classes instead. And you need to refer to each input with `jQuery(this)`, otherwise you're just referring to the first element with the class:

```js
jQuery(".round_inputs").live("change", function () {
    input_values = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val());
    if (isNaN(input_values)) input_values = "";
    jQuery(this).val(input_values.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="round_inputs" size="20" style="text-align:right" type="text" />
<br/>
<input class="round_inputs" size="20" style="text-align:right" type="text" />
<br/>
<input class="round_inputs" size="20" style="text-align:right" type="text" />
```

Also, as of jQuery 1.7 `.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()`, so consider updating your code accordingly.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I'd assume that at least some people did because of your repeated use of an ID.

Answer (score 3):

First off. `ID's` in a `HTML` page is supposed to be unique.

Use classes instead.

- Avoid inline styles , use CSS to keep your HTML clean.
- Inside the change handler use `$(this)` to target the element that triggered the event.
- Use `on` instead of `live` which is now deprecated.

**JS**

```
$(".round_inputs").on("change", function () {
    var input_values = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (isNaN(input_values)) input_values = "";
    $(this).val(input_values.toFixed(2));
});
```

HTML

```
<input class="round_inputs" size="20" type="text" />
<br/>
<input class="round_inputs" size="20" type="text" />
<br/>
<input class="round_inputs" size="20" type="text" />
<br/>
```

**CSS**

```
.round_inputs {
    text-align:right
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8641yv7/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

When using ID Selectors, jQuery will only ever return the first instance. You should use a classname selector for this:

```
 <input id="round_input1" class="round-input" size="20" style="text-align:right" type="text"/><br/>
```

And change your jQuery selector to:  `jQuery('.round-input')`

https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: Kevin I did your trick but is not working i'm using jquery 1.6.

Comment: Oops, I inadvertently added a _dot_ to the classname in the html. Fixed.